# PostgreSQL or SQLite3 for embedded application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, sqlite

We're are designing a Rails 4.1 application that will be deployed into small boxes, quite possibly ARM based (e.g. [CuBox-i2eX](http://cubox-i.com/products/)) or some cheaper [Intel NUC](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/nuc/overview.html) if ARM doesn't cut it.

There will be some other services running on the same box that will get most of the traffic and the Rails app is mostly there for administrative purposes with only minimal traffic most of the time, but should handle extensive workflows of a few people at times (entering data). The overall data volume would be small by most scales.

At this point it seems that SQLite3 would be ideal for this kind of application, but the managed data depicts students, teachers, etc LDAP-like schema and consists of many attributes that have multiple values (or structures), making it ideal for PostgreSQL's `array` and `h-store` datatypes and somewhat cumbersome to implement in SQLite3.

I'm aware of Rails's `serialize`, but I need to query at least some of those multi-valued columns, leaving me between options:

1. Bite the (memory) bullet and go with PostgreSQL, hoping it will not hog the little box
2. Create different tables/models for all such array-like attributes, e.g. `EmailAddress` and `TelephoneNumber`
3. A variant of [EAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model), but using Rails' Single Table Inheritance to make `EmailAddress < StringValue` and `TelephoneNumber < StringValue` and stich them together with Polymorphic Associations where needed, so that `StringValue` could belong to multiple models.

So my question is: are there any drawbacks when using STI and polymorphic associations together versus using full PostgreSQL install when I do not need one for performance.

Comment: It is my opinion, and I work with Rails every day, that by using Rails you are already biting the memory bullet. Have you thought about using Sinatra instead? That would no doubt free up memory for PostgreSQL. Also, read up on tuning PostgreSQL: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server

Comment: What memory limits are you dealing with? From what I can see, the  CuBox-i2eX has 1GB RAM? Is that correct? I've run Rails applications, backed by PostgreSQL, and background workers (Sidekiq), on less than that. PostgreSQL is happy with 100mb, and you can no doubt tune for lower limits. Most Rails apps will run at 150-200mb per instance (which can be further tuned), where one instance is usually sufficient for low usage.

Comment: PostgreSQL is quite happy in a really small amount of RAM, especially if you tune it down to lower connection limits, lock counts, etc and really cut `shared_buffers` to the bone. That said, SQLite is *much* more appropriate for this kind of lightweight, intermittent access use case. Among other things SQLite database files are compatible across a much wider range of versions; upgrading Pg when you release a firmware update will be a pain, but so will being stuck on some ancient unsupported version. I'd use SQLite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am biased old school, but personally I would normalise the data.  This gives you future proofing to generate queries that you hadn't thought about before.  I tend to favour sqlite when you haven't got security issues to worry about (in the sense that you want to hide some data from some applications/users) or I don't expect to have do much schema changing.  (ALTER TABLE is limited in SQLite).

I once tried to setup Postgresql on an android tablet, but ended up failing to be able to do so, because it tried to use kernel facilities (related to shared memory) which were unavailable.  If you want to try that direction ensure you can actually get it to run in your environment.

Comment: I would add that I run Redmine using Ruby/SQLite on a VPS that I rent. Before deloying it there I did run it for a short while on a 256Mb Raspberry PI (using nginx and thin) (along with Postfix/Dovecot mail stack - so it all fitted).  It was noticibly slower on the PI, although still perfectly usable.

Comment: At first I tended towards SQLite too, but then we thought that we might need a different webservice to access the database also in the long run. So PostgreSQL it will be.